# Server Error ASP.NET 2.0

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, webrequest

Hi Guys can you please help me with this error? What is it?

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> ---
>
> The request failed with HTTP status 400: Bad Request. 
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 400: Bad Request.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I've had this error when I've tried to run a .NET 2.0 web app with IIS set to .NET 1.1 for that virtual directory.

Answer (score 1):

My bet would either be that an incorrect version of .NET framework is assigned to the particular site, or you have not created a virtual directory for you web site.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: This can be a problem with IIS or ASP.NET installation. Try to restart/reinstall IIS.

Comment: yes i tried to restart the website and its pool. I can re-install IIS since I got other live websites :(

Answer (score 0):

http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E400.html

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/247249

Hope that helps.